# C++ - No matching function to call to

Tags: c++, c++11

I am making a singly linked list :

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int a;
    struct node *ptr;
};

node::node(int p) : {}

struct node *head;

void create(int d)
{
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head->a=d;
        head->ptr=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        struct node* temp =(struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp=head;
        while(temp==NULL)
            temp=temp->ptr;
        temp->a=d;
        temp->ptr=NULL;
    }

}

void display()
{
    struct node* temp =(struct node) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp=head;
    while(temp==NULL)
    {
        cout<<temp->a<<" --> ";
        temp=temp->ptr;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    head=NULL;
    create(5);
    create(6);
    create(8);
    display();
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting this error when I try to compile it:

```
..\linkedlist.cpp: In function 'void display()':
..\CPP\linkedlist.cpp:36:61: error: no matching function for call to 'node::node(void*)'
..\CPP\linkedlist.cpp:8:1: note: candidates are: node::node()
..\CPP\linkedlist.cpp:8:1: note:                 node::node(const node&)
```

Now, I am a rookie in coding and when I googled this problem, I found that a default constructor have to be constructed.
I know how to create a constructor but not a member initialized list constructor.

Comment: You likely meant `(struct node*) malloc(...)` (note the star). But what you really want is `node* temp = head` and drop `malloc`. You allocate memory, then immediately leak it. What do you believe this `malloc` call is for, exactly?

Comment: You can't define `node::node(int)` when it isn't declared in `struct node`. Your code makes no sense at all.

Comment: @cad But, this website states the use of malloc in the same way only,
http://geeksquiz.com/linked-list-set-2-inserting-a-node/

Comment: If it is C, alright. If it is C++, this website is to be banished from the Internet and all its traces annihilated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your completely broken code fixed using C++11. It still leaks memory on quit (you never delete the nodes), however:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    node(int a)
    : a(a)
    , ptr(nullptr)
    {}

    int a;
    node *ptr;
};

node* head = nullptr;

void create(int d)
{
    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        head = new node(d);
    }
    else
    {
        node* last = head;
        while (last->ptr != nullptr)
        {
            last = last->ptr;
        }
        last->ptr = new node(d);
    }
}

void display()
{
    node* temp = head;
    while (temp != nullptr)
    {
        cout << temp->a << " --> ";
        temp = temp->ptr;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    create(5);
    create(6);
    create(8);
    display();
    return 0;
}
```

Note that g++ requires -std=c++11 to compile the code.

Comment: Thank you so much, I used this stupid website for learning the language:
http://geeksquiz.com/linked-list-set-2-inserting-a-node/

Comment: When I compile your code, I get errors for using nullptr instead of NULL, I'm using mingw for compiling, any idea whats wrong?

Comment: You should set the standard with -std flag. Try to give -std=c++11 to mingw. Nullptr is a C++11 feature that should be used instead of NULL.